# T-SQL : xml how to add default namespace and root path with inner join

Tags: sql-server, xml

Objective: using SQL Server 2012, simplify the xml retrieval as much as possible. As starting point, specify default root path as well as default namespace.

Details:

the two tables are quite large, so using the indexes for the join is required. I've been unable to find an example that covers this scenario, although I've seen something similar when building an xml table using `FOR XML PATH`, type, Root=

SqlFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68df2/2/0

```
Create Table t1 (id int, MoreFields varchar(10), DateAdded datetime)
create Table t2 (id int, data xml)

--objective: Using the sql select structure below, make the default root path= /Doc/DocumentProperties

insert into t1 
values (1, 'other data', '2015-10-30 19:30:21.953'),
       (2, 'more data', '2015-10-30 19:30:21.953') 
insert into t2 
values (1,'<Doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.MyUrl.com" documentType="customDocument">
  <DocumentProperties>
    <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
    <Title>blah blah</Title>
    <DateAdded>2015-10-30T15:30:21.9538615-04:00</DateAdded>
    <VisitID>123456</VisitID>
    <Patient>
      <ID>9876</ID>
      <FirstName>john</FirstName>
      <LastName>doe</LastName>
      <MiddleName />
    </Patient>
  </DocumentProperties>
</Doc>')            

;with XMLNamespaces (DEFAULT 'http://www.MyUrl.com')           
select 
    t1.id
    ,t1.DateAdded
    ,xmlDateAdded=t2.data.value('(/Doc/DocumentProperties/DateAdded)[1]', 'datetime') 
    ,Objective='Make /Doc/DocumentProperties the default root path, simplify node value retrieval'
    --since everything is under DocumentProperties I want to do something like: 
    --,xmlDateAdded2    =t2.DateAdded   or
    --,xmlDateAdded3    =?.value('/DateAdded','datetime')

    --will be retrieving other node values as well.
from t1 
inner join t2 
    on t1.id=t2.id 
where t1.id=1--in real world criteria is multiple rows

drop table t1
drop table t2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do `CROSS APPLY` on `/Doc/DocumentProperties` to make it the context of the column XPath expressions, for example :

```
;with XMLNamespaces (DEFAULT 'http://www.MyUrl.com')           
select 
    t1.id
    ,t1.DateAdded
    ,xmlDateAdded=d.value('DateAdded[1]', 'datetime') 
from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
cross apply t2.data.nodes('/Doc/DocumentProperties') as x(d)
where t1.id=1
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbec6/8)</kbd>**

Notice that in the above example you can simply do `DateAdded[1]` in the column XPath instead of the much longer  `(/Doc/DocumentProperties/DateAdded)[1]`.